# Secure text entry TextField display white color Text in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

In my application I have implement 2 localize language "English" and "Thai". My problem is that when I change language "English" to "Thai" and enter password in SecureEntryTextField at that time "*" not display and it's force fully white colour. see on below gif.

I have try all the way for ex. 1) change textColor 2) set system default font 3) change password textField language.  but not get success.

[image]